# Count double occurrences in order list

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a list of orders, I need to find which ones occur with code 47 more than once with different users. For example:

```
ORDER_ID  CODE USER
111       47   1 
111       47   2
222       47   1
333       47   1
333       47   2
444       47   1
```

The expected result is 111 and 333.

How can I accomplish this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want aggregation and `having`:

```
select order_id
from orders o
where code = 47
group by order_id
having min(user) <> max(user);
```

You can also express the `having` as:

```
having count(distinct user) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select order_id from tablename
group by order_id
having count(distinct user)>=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via row_number() as well

```
    Select distinct order_id from

   (select order_id, code, row_number() 
    over
   ( Partition by order_id, code 
     Order by order_id, code) rn
     from 
    tablename
    where user in (1,2)
    ) where rn>=1
```

But I guess you already have a user column hence i dont think you require extra manipulation

```
   Select orderid, code from table 
  Group by orderid, code having 
   max(distinct user) >=1
```